# WCF and XML, returning XML from stored procedure

Tags: .net, wpf, xml, wcf, mvvm

I am returning XML from a stored procedure, that I want to capture in WCF and pass on to WPF view.

When I add function import, whats should be selected in returns a collection of, I selected string for now.

And then what should be the return type of the function that would return this data to wpf view, XmlDocument?

Comment: or should i try to use linq, itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have an arbitrary block of XML? Then yes, XmlDocument should make that available. The problem with just using a string is that it would get further encoded by WCF. If the layout of the XML is known, another option is deserializing it into an object model and returning *that*, which might make it easier to consume at the client. But XmlDocument should work.

XElement etc may also be worth a try if that is more convenient.

Comment: Its a fixed XMLList format like <item>value</item><item>value</item> returned from SP, how to deserialize? can't I bind an XMLList directly to a treeview component, like we are able to do that in Flex.

Comment: but thats for later, right now I am not able to understand what to add into returns a collection of when doing function import of the SP.

Comment: @NSingla if the XML isn't huge, I'd probably treat as string. For huge, ExeuteXmlReader

Comment: I have some trouble with string, when i debug for the linq which gets data from stored proc object and stores in a variable, and when i look at the results view of that variable, shows xml string or the first time, if i hover again then it says "the result of the query cannot be enumerated more than once"

Comment: @NSingla It sounds like you're actually keeping the `IQueryable<string>` or `IEnumerable<string>`. If it is multiple records, call `.ToList()` to get a concrete list. If you expect a single row, call `.First()`

Comment: This works, i did toList, thanks man, can you be my tutor Marc? :P

Comment: @NSingla I can't help with that; maybe start a separate question with some example xml